# How can I copy the first table after a specific string in XPath?

Tags: javascript, xpath, iframe

I'm a bit stuck on this problem. My HTML markup looks something like

```
<body>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<iframe>
#document
    <html>
        <body>
            <div>
                <span> TABLE OF CONTENTS </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table>
                    ...
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The issue is that there are multiple tables, but I want to copy the first table directly after the "Table of Contents" string. Would I be able to get some help on how to write the XPath code for this?

Here is my attempts:
I have been trying variations of
'''
//span[text()="TABLE OF CONTENTS"]/following-sibling::table
'''
but nothing seems to be working... I think one issue might be my xPath is off... Another I think is that I can't access stuff in the iFrame

Answer (score 0):

Try using this xpath expression

```
//div[span[contains(.,"TABLE OF CONTENTS")]]/following-sibling::div/table
```

and see if it works.